# Matlab how to distribute a matrix elements randomly

Tags: matlab, matrix, distribute

hi everyone how to make a matrix randomly distributed to another matrix n,

```
m = [ 1 1 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 7 7 7];
n = zeros(3,10);
```

the same value must in the sequence, ex : 4 4 4, 7 7 7.result reqiured can be something like {or other combinations):

```
distributed_matrix =

 0     1     1     0     7     7     7     0     0     0
 0     0     3     3     3     4     4     0     0     0
 6     6     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

thank you...

Comment: do you require the sequences (`1, 1`, `3 3 3` etc.) to "stay together"?

Comment: yes, they have stay together...

Comment: Can the same values be split across rows of `n`? That is `[... 7 7; 7 ...]`?

Comment: no, it can't...it must be in the same row...
thank you..

Comment: what if `m` has a value with more than `size(n,2)` in a sequence? it will not fit a row...

Comment: then m will be put in the next row, and let the rest is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not impose any constraint on the order at which the elements of `m` are distributed, then [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) might help:

```
ridx = randsample( numel(n), numel(m) ); %// sample new idices for elelemtns
n(ridx) = m;
```

---

Looking into the [additional constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940634/matlab-how-to-distribute-a-matrix-elements-randomly?noredirect=1#comment67162826_39940634), things get a bit more messy.
For identifying the sequences and their extent in `m`, you can:

```
idx = [1 find(diff(m)~=0)+1]; 
extent = diff([idx numel(m)+1]);  %// length of each sequence
vals = m(idx);  %// value of each sequence
```

Once you have the sequqnces and their length you can randomly shuffle them and then distribute along the lines...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the possible solution is

```
m = [ 1 1 3 3 3 4 4 6 6 7 7 7];
n = zeros(3,10);
p= randperm(numel(n)); % generate the random permutation
n(p(1:length(m)))= m   % assign the elments of m to the elements with indices taken 
                       % from the first length(m) numbers of random permutation
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how to make the same value stay in the sequence?
thank you...